# Azure PolyBase external table from binary blob data?

Tags: azure, hadoop, binary-data, external-tables, polybase

I have several million image blobs stored in a Azure storage container.  The blobs have a predictable name ([unique key].jpg.)

Examples:  1234.jpg, 230.jpg & so on.

If possible, how can I create an external table using this data which can be retrieved using a Sql statement?

`Select PK, IMAGE_CONTENT from external_blah`

Which gives me the following:

PK IMAGE_CONTENT

1234 [Content of 1234.jpg]

230  [Content of 230.jpg]